# How do I make a cell value represent a number in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have

Year 1  2  3  4  5  6

I'm trying to make it so that each year number 1-6 is equal to another number value i.e. Year 1 is equal to 5. Year 2 is equal to 6.

Comment: Are those numbers coming from somewhere? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, I want to be able to change the value that Year 1 equals. I've tried using Lookup and countif but I'm not sure if they are right. To clarify if I write Year 1 in cell A1, I want the value of that cell to be equal to another number(let's say 5), so that A1 will display "Year 1" but when I multiply A1 by 2, I would get 10, since Year 1 is equal to 5.

Comment: if you are trying to build something mostly static - a fixed set of a to b relationships you could put it all into an IF statement ie:=IF(A2=1,5,IF(A2=2,6,IF(A2=3,7,IF(A2=4,8,IF(A2=5,9,10)))))

Comment: @trapspring better to use a vlookup if possible as an option. Multiple if statements can lead to a very long and complicated formula which can get difficult to debug or change if and when required.

Comment: You could use a custom format to do this. However it would be better to use a hidden sheet, or column to contain a look up list

Comment: @parry chen can you share your tries in your edit and why you think they are not working

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to store one value in a cell and use a different value for calculation. However you may do this calculation with the help of a lookup from another table,

Assuming you have the years in `Column A` and the corresponding mappings are in `Column E and F`, you can use the below formula in `Column B`,

```
=INDEX(E:F,MATCH(A1,E:E,0),2) * 2
```

[image]

This formula lookups the value in `A1` in the table `E:F` and returns the corresponding `Column F` element. That is finally multiplied with the `2` to show your result. Instead of just using just `A1` for multiplying by 2, you should be using `INDEX(E:F,MATCH(A1,E:E,0),2)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @pnuts What if Year 1 has to be mapped to 5 and year 2 to 13? an so on.. with random values